# How to back out of Application from any point.

Tags: android

I have an application that accesses a server.  I have many activities that access the server for data.  At various points in the application, I do a simple check to verify two things, 1) There is internet connectivity and 2) The server is not in maintenance mode or down.. If it is, I display an Activity detailing why and when the server will be back up.

When a user clicks back in this "Server is down" Activity, I need to exit the application.  I have tried the following code/intent to call the "Server Down" activity but it doesn't work.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ServerMaintenanceActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

I have looked all over and this is a very common problem faced with people typically on login/logout screens.  None of the solutions I find works for me.  I know it's possible because I have apps that do just this for example Spotify.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you start an activity, you can create new [`ResultReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) then put it into a list, in a global helper class. Then, in your notification activity (telling the user "Server is down"), override `onDestroy()` and send request to finish others.

For example:

- `Helper` class:

  ```
  public static final int REQUEST_FINISH = 1;

  private static final List<ResultReceiver> mClients = new ArrayList<ResultReceiver>();

  public static void registerClient(ResultReceiver receiver) {
      mClients.add(receiver);
  }

  public static void unregisterClient(ResultReceiver receiver) {
      mClients.remove(receiver);
  }

  public static void finishApp() {
      for (ResultReceiver client : mClients)
          client.send(REQUEST_FINISH, null);
  }
  ```
- Other activities:

  ```
  private ResultReceiver mCommandHandler;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // ...

      mCommandHandler = new ResultReceiver(null) {

          @Override
          public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
              if (resultCode == Helper.REQUEST_FINISH) {
                  // do some other stuffs...

                  finish();
              }
          }
      };

      Helper.registerClient(mCommandHandler);
  }// onCreate()

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Helper.unregisterClient(mCommandHandler);
  }
  ```
- Notification activity:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Helper.finishApp();
  }
  ```

Comment: Excellent example, and the best way to do this.  Thank you.

Comment: Except, now when I am trying to implement it.. The constructor for ResultReceiver requires Handler as a param.  That seems to be lacking in the code above.

Comment: @ToddPainton Thanks. I missed that. In your case you can pass `null` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the `ServerMaintenanceActivity`, finish the current one, so when you'll press Back it should be removed from the stack.

```
//...
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: Yes, I actually do that. Problem is.. there might be a stack of 5 activities, so I just pass to the next on stack...

Answer (score 0):

Remove Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. If you start new activity with NEW_TASK flag it starts new task. You do not want new task, you want to clean all current task activities stack. So remove FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
P.S. closing all activities this way is not the best solution, ResultReceiver is better.